# Enable memory debugging TCL on windows Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, tcl

I have been trying for a while now to get this to work, but it doesn't seem to want to. My program uses OpenGL and Tcl libraries in C code

My steps:

1. Download Tcl/tk source code
2. Compile and install Tcl/tk source code using commands in the following order:

`nmake -f makefile.vc INSTALLDIR = "" STATS=memdbg`

`nmake -f makefile.vc install INSTALLDIR = "" STATS=memdbg`

`nmake -f makefile.vc INSTALLDIR = "" TCLDIR=""`

`nmake -f makefile.vc install INSTALLDIR = "" TCLDIR=""`

3. Open Visual studio and link static libraries `tclstub64.lib` and `tkstub64.lib`
4. Place `#define TCL_MEM_DEBUG` in my main header file
5. Replace all `Tcl_Alloc()` and `Tcl_Free()` calls with `ckalloc()` and `ckfree()`
6. Strategically place `Tcl_ValidateAllMemory(__FILE__,__LINE__)`
7. Compile program in x64 DEBUG mode, and attach process to application that calls commands that live in the C code

This does not work, and I have not an idea why.

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  Will not compile?  Will not link? Runs, but aborts?  What?

Comment: It compiles fine and seemingly links fine. However, the TCL memory debugging function `Tcl_ValidateAllMemory()` does not do anything when called.

Comment: The debug-only functions get do-nothing dummies when compiled in non-debug mode so that their ABI stays the same.

Comment: @DonalFellows the code should be compiled in debug mode though, which is where I am lost.